# host a WCF services which returns a list of instances of a datacontract

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to visual studio. I create a datacontract about book information. I create a WCF web services parsing a txt file and create a list of instance of that book information.

When I was trying to call this service to get book information and displace on a web form. I found I don't know how to access Datamember of those instance. Can anybody help me?

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Book> GetAllBooks();
    [OperationContract]
    String SearchBookById();
}

[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Num { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string author { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int year { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float price { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int stock { get; set; }
}

public List<Book> GetAllBooks()
{
    var bookList = new List<Book>();
    int n = 1;

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\infs 7204\prac3\books(1).txt");
    {
        string fileLine;
        while((fileLine = reader.ReadLine())!= null)
        {
            string[] bookInfo = fileLine.Split(',');
            int year = Int32.Parse(bookInfo[3]);
            float price = float.Parse(bookInfo[4].Trim('$'));
            int stock = Int32.Parse(bookInfo[5]);
            bookList.Add(new Book { Num = n, ID = bookInfo[0], name = bookInfo[1], author=bookInfo[2],
            year=year,price=price, stock=stock});
            n++;

        }
    }
    return bookList;
}
```

I need to display those book classes in a table on my webpage. Here is how I want to access the datacontract list. But I got an warrning says "Cannot implicitly convert type'prac3.ServiceReference1.Book[] to 'prac3.Book[]'"

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Book[] list= client.GetAllBooks();


    }
}
```

Also, Is there any segesstion about which conponent in toolbox should I use to display the table?

Comment: Post your error as well. Hard to answer without error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warning `Cannot implicitly convert type'prac3.ServiceReference1.Book[] to 'prac3.Book[]` indicates that very likely you have duplicate definition of type `Book`.

There are two possibilities:

1. More likely, as Servé Laurijssen has already pointed out, your client project might have a project reference to your service project. Hence you have access to all of the public types defined within it (including `Book`.) To be sure if your client project has reference to service project: open your client project in Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer expand the *References* node under your client project, and find if your service project's name appear there.
2. Or, less likely, you have redefined class `Book` in your client project.

In both cases, you get two definitions of `Book`: one `prac3.Book` (defined in service project) and another `prac3.ServiceReference1.Book` (generated by service reference in client project, usually in the file *Service References\Service Namespace Name\Reference.cs* under your client project directory.) In your case, you are trying to set a `prac3.ServiceReference1.Book` array to a `prac3.Book` one, hence causing a type mismatch.

For an immediate remedy change the following line in your client code

```
Book[] list= client.GetAllBooks();
```

to the following

```
prac3.ServiceReference1.Book[] list= client.GetAllBooks();
```

And consider removing the reference to the service project or the duplicate definition. It is very unusual a client has reference to a service assembly that it refers as well.

Comment: Problem solved! I add an new web application to consume that service instead of just adding an webworm item in the application which contains the service. The error is gone. Thank you. Now I want to display all the class of the data-contract in an excel-alike table on a webpage. How do you suggest me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the full namespace of Book and see if it works.
Have you added a project reference to the Book class and generated a service reference also? If that's thje case, better remove the project reference and let svcutil generate a common namespace with ädd service reference".

```
List<prac3.ServiceReference1.Book> books = client.GetAllBooks();

foreach (prac3.ServiceReference1.Book book in books)
{
  Console.WriteLine(book.author);
}
```

Comment: I got error writing similar code. And I don't understand why those error occur. I add the client end code in my question. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean..  Data contract and operation contract are under same namespace in the same service file. I added the service reference for sure.